# how to check lottery wining numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, alasql

**Objective**

I wish to query a excel spread sheet to check the numbers entered in the html form are winning numbers.

**Winning numbers**

winning numbers would be if the first, second, third, fourth fifth, and sixth number entered in the HTML matches the numbers in excel spread sheet in the same row in columns c, d, e, f, h and i.

I have a excel spread sheet called `results` in my project folder.

**Question**

Can anyone help me query every row in the spread sheet and print winner or looser if numbers match or not.

**My current Code (HTML)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.4.2/alasql-worker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form onsubmit="checkIfYouHaveWinningNumber(); return false;">
    Your numbers:
    <input type="number" name="first"
           min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" name="second"
           min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" name="third"
           min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" name="fourth"
           min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" name="fifth"
           min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" name="sixth"
           min="0" max="100">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**My current code (JavaScript)**

```
    var data = [{a:3,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
var lotteryNumbers = alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("results") FROM ?',[data]);


function checkIfYouHaveWinningNumber(number)
{
    if(contains(number))
    {
        alert("Congratulation you won - " + number);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You lose - " + number);
    }
}

function contains(number)
{
    for(var i = 0;i < lotteryNumbers.length;i++)
    {
        if(lotteryNumbers[i] == number)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you post how the `data` object will look like after it has been populated by `alasql()`?

Comment: I just want to check that the numbers i enter matches the spread sheet. the data is just standard spread sheet data

Comment: Sorry I meant `lotteryNumbers`. How is that object structured? Can you post what you get when you call `console.log(JSON.stringify(lotteryNumbers))`?

Comment: sure give me 5 mins